# How can I make the background on top like the SVG at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this website. I am trying to make the banner background like the svg image at the bottom. I don't want to use a picture as the background, so I have been using CSS background-image. I am using clip-path because it makes it easier to hide portion of the picture.

Is there any way I can make the point where the bottom left corner radius meet with the straight line rounded, so it can look like the SVG image at the bottom, please?

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 800px;

    background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #6c2aad 0%, rgb(44, 80, 199) 74%);

    clip-path: polygon(
        0 0,
        100% 0,
        100% calc(100% - 200px),
        0 100%
    );
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 50%;
}

.header-bg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


#banner-content {
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

#banner-image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#banner-image-container {
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin: 0 7%;
    height: 410px;
}

#right-side {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0 7%;
    max-width: 420px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}

#right-side p:first-child {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 551px) {

    #right-side {
        align-self: center;
        margin: 0 7%;
    }
}

#banner-content img {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 724px) {
    #banner-content {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    #banner-image-container {
        align-self: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header id="banner">
      <div class="header-bg"></div>
      <div id="banner-content">
          <div id="banner-image-container">
            <img src="http://webcomics.co/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2010/09/James-mugshot.png" alt=""/>
          </div>
          <div id="right-side">
              <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </header>
<div class="back">



  <svg width="1600px" height="612px" viewBox="0 0 1600 612" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
          <path d="M0,0.111104331 L1600,5.68434189e-14 L1600,344.091288 C1112.04518,489.644113 740.739648,576.663624 486.083401,605.14982 C376.998796,617.352174 281.625713,612.768489 207.849921,583.94285 C136.196666,555.946528 66.9133592,475.996007 0,344.091288 L0,0.111104331 Z" id="path-1"></path>
      </defs>
      <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Artboard">
              <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                  <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
              </mask>
              <use id="Mask" fill="#071246" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it using pseudo element and some rotation combined with radius:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 800px;
  z-index: 0;
}

header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #6c2aad 0%, rgb(44, 80, 199) 74%);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 35% 35%;
  transform: rotate(-18deg);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.header-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#banner-content {
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

#banner-image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
}

#banner-image-container {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin: 0 7%;
  height: 410px;
}

#right-side {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 7%;
  max-width: 420px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

#right-side p:first-child {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 551px) {
  #right-side {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 0 7%;
  }
}

#banner-content img {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 724px) {
  #banner-content {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  #banner-image-container {
    align-self: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="banner">
  <div class="header-bg"></div>
  <div id="banner-content">
    <div id="banner-image-container">
      <img src="http://webcomics.co/wp-content/uploads/sites/10/2010/09/James-mugshot.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="right-side">
      <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="back">



  <svg width="1600px" height="612px" viewBox="0 0 1600 612" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
          <path d="M0,0.111104331 L1600,5.68434189e-14 L1600,344.091288 C1112.04518,489.644113 740.739648,576.663624 486.083401,605.14982 C376.998796,617.352174 281.625713,612.768489 207.849921,583.94285 C136.196666,555.946528 66.9133592,475.996007 0,344.091288 L0,0.111104331 Z" id="path-1"></path>
      </defs>
      <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="Artboard">
              <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                  <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
              </mask>
              <use id="Mask" fill="#071246" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
          </g>
      </g>
  </svg>
```